# What's causing pMoniker->BindToObject to return 800700c1

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

The capture device is valid, but i failed to bind it.  800703E8 usually means filter unregistered. win10-64

```
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                char tempDevicePathUTF8[256];
                memset(tempDevicePathUTF8,0,256);
                tempDevicePathUTF8[0] = 0;
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, varName.bstrVal, -1,
                                    tempDevicePathUTF8,
                                    sizeof(tempDevicePathUTF8), NULL,
                                    NULL);
                if (strncmp(tempDevicePathUTF8,
                            (const char*) deviceUniqueIdUTF8,
                            deviceUniqueIdUTF8Length) == 0)
                {
                    // We have found the requested device
                    deviceFound = true;
                    hr = pM->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter,
                                          (void**) &captureFilter);
                    if FAILED(hr)
                    {
                        WEBRTC_TRACE(webrtc::kTraceError, webrtc::kTraceVideoCapture,
                                     _id, "Failed to bind to the selected capture device %d",hr);
                    }

                    if (productUniqueIdUTF8
                        && productUniqueIdUTF8Length > 0) // Get the device name
                    {

                        GetProductId(deviceUniqueIdUTF8,
                                     productUniqueIdUTF8,
                                     productUniqueIdUTF8Length);
                    }

                }
            }
```

it's a common capture step in webrtc and can perform well in most of the computers, but this specific one cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x800700C1` is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` which indicates a problem with the capture device (even though you suppose it's valid). One of typical problem is that the device is correctly registered for 32-bit applications but not for 64-bit (or vice versa). Either way, it's a COM registration problem of specific DirectShow filter.